# error when creating ".": persistentvolumeclaims "wp-pv-claim" is forbidden: exceeded quota

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to run WordPress by using [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/) link, and the only change is I changed `20Gi` to `5Gi`, but when I run `kubectl apply -k .`, I get this error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating ".": persistentvolumeclaims "wp-pv-claim" is forbidden: exceeded quota: storagequota, requested: requests.storage=5Gi, used: requests.storage=5Gi, limited: requests.storage=5Gi
```

I searched but did not find any related answer to mine (or even maybe I'm wrong).

Could you please answer me these questions:

1. How to solve the above issue?
2. If the volume's size is limited to 5G, then the pod cannot be bigger than 5G? I mean if I exec into the pod and run a command like `dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=8000`, should it create an 8G file or not? I mean this quota and volume limits whole the pod? Or only a specific path like `/var/www/html`?

**Edit 1**

```
describe pvc mysql-pv-claim
Name:          mysql-pv-claim
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=wordpress
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       wordpress-mysql-6c479567b-vzpm5
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                 From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  4m (x222 over 59m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Comment: It seems that you have already created a 5Gi pv (`kubectl get pv`). Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Matt the respond is: `No resources found`. I deleted everything and then run `kubectl apply -k .` again but got the same error

Comment: What does your request quota show? `kubectl get resourcequotas storagequota`

Comment: What does `kubectl get pvc` show? You may have pvc already created without an actual pv and it will also count as used storage.

Comment: `NAME           AGE   REQUEST                                                  LIMIT
storagequota   22h   persistentvolumeclaims: 1/5, requests.storage: 5Gi/5Gi` it shows a pvc. I deleted this and pvc again. Now pvcs are in `pending`, and `kubecget get resourcequotas` shows `Error from server (NotFound): resourcequotas "storagequota" not found`

Comment: Run: `kubectl describe pvc mysql-pv-claim`, and check the events section. What does it say?

Comment: @Matt I edited the question and added it

Comment: `no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set` - where do you run your cluster? Do you have any storageclass defined (`kubectl get storageclass`)? [storageclass in k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)

Comment: @Matt it is `No resources found`. It's a single node I run on.

Comment: You need a storage class and some storage provider (sth that will actually create a pv and mount it) to make use of persistent volumes. I assume you created your cluster with kubeadm (presumably) so that's on you to deploy some storage provider. If you just want to try k8s please use minkube as it already has a storage provider out of the box.

Comment: @Matt yes I created the cluster with `kubeadm` but in fact the reason I use kubernetes alone is that I need it. I added a `storage.yaml` to `kustomization.yaml` with `local` class as above you linked, Now when I run `kubectl apply -k .`, I see they're still pending after one hour with no logs

Comment: In the same link above is menioned: `Local volumes do not currently support dynamic provisioning [...]`. This means that you need to [create a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) manually. Quote from docs: `Local volumes can only be used as a statically created PersistentVolume. Dynamic provisioning is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to summarize our comments conversation for better readability and visibility.

The issue at first seemed to be caused by resourcequota.

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating ".": persistentvolumeclaims "wp-pv-claim" is forbidden: exceeded quota: storagequota, requested: requests.storage=5Gi, used: requests.storage=5Gi, limited: requests.storage=5Gi

It looked like there was already existing PVC and it wouldn't allow to create a new one.

OP removed the resource quota although it was not necessary in this case since the real issue was with the PVC.

`kubectl describe pvc mysql-pv-claim` showed the following event:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                 From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  4m (x222 over 59m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Event message:

> **persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set**

Since OP created the cluster with kubeadm and kubeadm doesn't come with a predeployed storage provider out of the box; this means that it needs to be added manually. (Storage Provider is a controller that can create a volume and mount it).

Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. Since there was no storage class in cluster, OP decided to create one and picked [Local storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) but forgot that:

> Local volumes do not currently support dynamic provisioning [...].

and

> Local volumes can only be used as a statically created PersistentVolume. Dynamic provisioning is not supported

This means that a local volume had to be [created manually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I'm trying to fix, but I think it's because I'm newbie to K8S and it still does not answer me. @Matt I really thank you for your attention, but still when I run `kubectl describe pvc mysql-pv-claim`, I see what I wrote in the question

Comment: I mean I have created a file with the contents of https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local and then ran it